# Can anyone identify what set these may have come from? Lots of burgundy colored pieces and a few Technic pieces

Tags: set-identification

[image]

The year listed is 2011, but I really have no other information as these were salvaged from a thrift store.

Answer (score 4):

Based on

[SLIDE SHOE ROUND 2X2](https://brickset.com/parts/design-2654) in red

[SLIDE SHOE ROUND 2X2](https://brickset.com/parts/design-54196) in trans yellow

and the different gray parts

these bags are from[image]

[7964: Republic Frigate](https://brickset.com/sets/7964-1/Republic-Frigate)

Comment: "SLIDE SHOE ROUND 2X2", what a name... Also known as "Plate, Round 2 x 2 with Rounded Bottom (Boat Stud)" on Bricklink.

Comment: Thank you! Too bad I didn't have the other bags.